# What algorithm is used for Pos() function in Pascal?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pascal, string-search

As title, Brute Force, Karp-Rabin, Knutt-Morris-Pratt, Boyer Moore, ... or else? And what complexity of Pos() function in Pascal?

Comment: probably depend son the compiler

Comment: You will have to specify which pascal compiler you mean. Generally I would assume brute force, and if you want a specific algorithm you will have to find a library or code it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi it is handcoded assembler brute force. Potentially in D2006 and higher redone by fastcode project. In Turbo Pascal it was handcoded assembler too, but older (probably rep scasb)

On Free Pascal it uses indexbyte() which is a architecture dependent primitive "search byte in block of memory", implemented by dword wise scanning.

IOW it simply scans for the first equal char, so I assume that is what you mean with brute force.

There are various Delphi Boyer Moore implementations that can be used, in case you have to search through larger texts, but due to their additional memory allocation these usually score bad on short strings.

(2020-06-04 after a Lazarus forum post referencing this thread:

Meanwhile there is a [BMH implementation in the RTL](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/findmatchesboyermoorecasesensitive.html) 
)